# Running SVN as a service on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, svn

I currently am running SVN on my Windows Server 2003 as a module in Apache.

Is it possible to set up SV to run as a Windows service as well? The goal is to access the repositories via `svn://servername` and `http://servername`?

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

Apart from VisualSVN you can also look [CollabNet SVN](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) that includes automatic checking of updates.

However it can be done with the base SVN server directly using this guide from the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#svnserve-win-service) as the support is built into the SVN executable.

Comment: +1 Just did this last week for a client following those instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried VisualSvn server ?
It's much more easier to set it up using it for windows server, and the standard edition is free.

Plus it works just like you wanted to.

[VisualSvn Website](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)