# Windows 2008 Server and Subversion

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, networking

I have a box with Windows 2008 Server, and I installed SVN.
I want to connect to svn from a different Windows 2008 Server, and they are on the same network, both are in my office.
Do I need to configure the box with the SVN server to accept connections from other computers, for when I try to connect, using Torotise Repo Browser (svn:///repo) I get a cannot connect, but I can using same method on the box (localhost) that houses SVN.

Comment: the connection to the svn server from the remote box is svn://some.ip/repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure the firewall on Server 2008 to open up the SVN port? That is a necessary step to allow access from another machine. Which port you have to open up depends on how you configured your SVN server.

Comment: The port is 3690 for reference.

Comment: I was about to edit my post to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at setting up the SVN Server to run as service, which will ensure you can connect to it. You can find out how to do this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/115138/running-svn-as-a-service-on-windows-server-2003/115290#115290). The instructions are the same for both versions.

Comment: i have it running as a service, so that means I can connect to it from a remote box?

Comment: As mentioned by electronherder it will work as long as you have the firewall port open and the service pointing to the root of the repo, or use the full path to the repo. The port is 3690.